# What causes the network validation loss to always be lower than train loss?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I am using a LSTM model to predict values in a time-series based network. However, my problem is that every time, I get consistently the validation loss lower than the training loss. Even at the starting of the epochs, the model always has validation loss lower than train loss which seems weird to me. Basically, I have created a subset of my Training Data (which after splitting into Validation has 42005 samples), which I use for validation (having 10502 samples). And then, there is a separate test set, which is used to evaluate the RMSE and MAPE for the network. I use a test set with 17667 samples for this very purpose.

The following outlines the essence of the network:-

```
# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer= 'Adam') # also try mae

# fit network
es = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, verbose=1 , mode='min')
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs= 100, batch_size= 512  , validation_data=(val_X, val_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False, callbacks= [es])
```

I have also tried various batch sizes, including 128, 512, 1024, and even lower values like 10,20,40 etc., and also with only 1 dense layer or multiple dense layers, but always the test loss is lower than train and due to early stopping, the model stops at at most 5-6 epochs, which seems very weird. The loss curve for the network is accordingly shown in [image: Loss curve for the network]

I have looked at Stackexchange, Keras Documentation and related blogs, but still, the problem isn't clear to me. Any help and suggestions on how I can resolve this would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Used activation function 'tanh' as per:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
```

New loss curve is still weird as in :- [image: New Loss curve after EDIT (with activation function in dense layer)]

Comment: In this model, Dense layers do not have any activation function. Is usage of Linear activation intentional ?

Comment: No. It's not intentional, as I was not sure of how to add dense layers, and I have added them in this fashion. Please refer to the edit, I tried this with 'tanh' activation as well, but the results are still similar.

Comment: What are min and max values of output variable in train and test sets ?

Comment: The output is already scaled to range 0-1 using MinMaxScaler.

Comment: What's the point of the second dense layer? It also outputs just one value

Comment: Looks like validation error is only lower before training in epoch 0? That isn't really surprising if the initial weight is random

Comment: So do you think the network isn’t overfitting/underfitting? I tried without early stopping as well, though it converges to a minimal value after 100 epochs, but validation error increases in middle then decreases. Is it alright in case of converging for the network? I’m asking this as all this is a bit confusing to me in the first instance, as the curve looks strange. Thanks